# Extracting dates from filenames and adding them to data.frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I combine 12 different txt files into a dataframe, which looks like this:

Each file contains a different number of data, and the file name was name with the date, e.g. "Student-Score-2010-10.txt".

Each file represents one month.

How can I add back the date to each row?

```
   id  dep  score
id511   10     34
id512   10     32
id512   10     34
```

I need to add back the date to each row

```
   id  dep  score      date
id511   10     34   2010-10
id511   10     34   2010-10
id511   10     34   2010-10
id511   10     34   2010-11
id511   10     34   2010-11
id511   10     34   2010-12
id511   10     34    2011-1
```

I made up the date. It is not the real data

orignial data

Monthly report"

"University of XXXXX"

"+--------+------+-----+"

"| id | dep | scores |

"+-------+-----+------+

"| id593 | 2 | 233 |

Comment: Use something like `Map(cbind, files, gsub("[A-za-z.-]", "", names(files))` before combining them into one data frame, where `files` is your list of data frames that you've pulled

Comment: @akrun no it's not.I have to put 12 different files into one dataframe/

Comment: @davidArenburg I used your code and it shows "Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length"

Comment: Please show how your data looks before you combine them into one data frame

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind,lapply(files, function(x) cbind(read.table(x,header=TRUE), date= gsub("[[:alpha:]]+\\-[[:alpha:]]+\\-(.*)\\.txt", "\\1",x))))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I've just put my original data on the post =)

Comment: @Emilia311 I guess this is the data from your previous post. Have you tried the solution in that other post?

Comment: @akun.Yes I have solved that already,thanks for that =)

Comment: @Emilia311 So, you wanted to work with the same datasets from the list and get into the format you showed?

Comment: @akun yes,plz.that's what I want.

Comment: @Emilia311 I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 files <- list.files(pattern="^Student")
  files
 #[1] "Student-Score-2010-10.txt" "Student-Score-2010-11.txt"

 dat<- do.call(rbind,lapply(files, function(x) {
           al <- readLines(x)
           al2 <- grep("id[0-9]", al, value=TRUE)
           al3 <- gsub("^ +| +$", "", gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", al2))
           al4 <-read.table(text=al3, header=FALSE, sep="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
           colnames(al4) <- c("id", "dep", "scores")
           transform(al4, date=gsub("[[:alpha:]]+\\-[[:alpha:]]+\\-(.*)\\.txt",
                                          "\\1",x))}))

  dat
  #   id dep scores    date
  #1 id592   2    235 2010-10
  #2 id593   2    233 2010-11
```